# Spark and remote properties-files

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I try to launch a oozie which launches spark. I need to specify it a properties-files . But this properties files has to be on hdfs

spark-submit --properties-files hdfs:/user/lele/app.properties ....

doesn't work.
Do you have any idea to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [Oozie documentation for Spark extension](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html)

> **Spark Action Schema Version 0.2**
>  ...
>     <xs:element name=**"file"** type="xs:string"
>   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

*(looks like it was forgotten in V0.1 ?!? that was a blunder...)*

And in the [Oozie documentation for core Oozie Workflow features](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2.1_Adding_Files_and_Archives_for_the_Job)

> The `file`, `archive` elements make available, to map-reduce jobs,
>   files and archives ... Files specified with the `file` element, will
>   be symbolic links in the home directory of the task.
>  Refer to
>   Hadoop distributed cache documentation for details more details on
>   files and archives.

Unfortunately that's just noise, and does not explain what `file` actually does: it **downloads an HDFS file into the YARN container(s) running the Oozie action**, and makes it available in the Current Working Dir.
In option, you can get the file renamed e.g. `<file>/user/dummy/wtf.conf.V5.2.0#wtf.conf</file>` will fetch a specific version on HDFS and make it available to the job under a generic name.

---

---

*Recommended reading:* the [Hooked on Hadoop tutorial series about Oozie](http://hadooped.blogspot.fr/2013/10/apache-oozie-part-13-oozie-ssh-action_30.html). Now a bit old, but still the best overview of what Oozie can do in practise.

Comment: the file property is used for map-reduce action. It doesn't work with spark action 
Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'file'. One of '{"uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1":arg}' is expected.

Comment: _"uri:oozie:spark-action: **0.1**"_ >> As I wrote in my answer, it works if you request schema in version **0.2**